# Blend for Visual Studio - Show App Bar in Design Mode

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, blend, winjs, appbar

How do I see the **App Bar** in design mode while using Blend for Visual Studio 2012 RC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default for **Split App**, you have to uncomment the AppBar that is commented out by default.

Change this:

```xml
<!-- <div id="appbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar">
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmd', label:'Command', icon:'placeholder'}"></button>
  </div> -->
```

to this:

```xml
 <div id="appbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar">
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmd', label:'Command', icon:'placeholder'}"></button>
  </div>
```

Then right-click on the `appbar` in the **Live DOM pane** and select **Activate AppBar**.

Kudos goes to [Matt Hidinger](http://www.matthidinger.com/) for sharing this helpful tip.